# Create a new variable that equals the text variable with the minimum number of characters within a group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with a factor variable, and an ID that helps group these factors. Here is my example data frame and accompanying code that currently doesn't get the correct answer:

```
library(dplyr)
names <- c("Andrew","Andrew","Andy","Andy","Alex","Alexander")
name.id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
df1 <- data.frame(names, name.id)

df1 <-  group_by(df1,name.id) %>%
        mutate(name.len=nchar(as.character(names)))  %>%
        mutate(new.name = min(as.character(names)))
```

I want the new.name variable to equal the name within the ID grouping that has the lowest char count (name.len). The variable should be "Alex" for ID=1, but using a minimum variable only compares characters within every digit, causing the 'r' in "Andrew" to be lower the 'y' in "Andy". I do not know how to do a conditional variable that gets this factor associated with the minimum nchar value within groups

EDIT:
To be more clear, I would like for my final data to look like the following (helper columns are fine too):

```
      names name.id new.names
1    Andrew       1      Andy
2    Andrew       1      Andy
3      Andy       1      Andy
4      Andy       1      Andy
5      Alex       2      Alex
6 Alexander       2      Alex
```

Comment: You need a `substr` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(name.id) %>% mutate(newname = substr(names, 1, min(nchar(as.character(names)))))`

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(name.id) %>% mutate(new.name = names[which.min(nchar(names))])` when `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is used to construct the dataframe, else `df1 %>% group_by(name.id) %>% mutate(new.name = names[which.min(nchar(as.character(names)))])`

Comment: Do you care what happens if there is a tie? If Group 3 is `"Jonathan", "Jack", "John"`, do you care if the result is Jack or John?

Comment: Hey @Gregor, for this exercise, it isn't super important if there is a tie, as long as there is a consistent answer for each name.id.

Comment: Jaap, this is actually the answer I'm looking for, so if you submitted it as a response, then I could accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on `name.id` and then `sort` on number of characters in `names`. Finally, pick top most row for each group.

A solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% group_by(name.id) %>%
  mutate(newname = first(names, order_by = nchar(as.character(names)))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#       names name.id newname
# 1    Andrew       1    Andy
# 2    Andrew       1    Andy
# 3      Andy       1    Andy
# 4      Andy       1    Andy
# 5      Alex       2    Alex
# 6 Alexander       2    Alex
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, MKR. That said, I am looking to preserve every row and simply add a new row that shows the shorter name. I've edited my question to reflect the final data I am looking to shape.

Comment: @AnalystGuy I have updated the answer. Actually you have to use `first` with `order_by`.